# Python unittest via ANT build script gets ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ant, python-unittest

I am having an issue running Python tests using discovery.

It works when run from Terminal via 'python3 -m unittest discover' or from inside BBEdit but not from my ANT build script.

The Error is:

```
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 346, in discover
    raise ImportError('Start directory is not importable: %r' % start_dir)
ImportError: Start directory is not importable: ' /Users/<username>/Documents/Work/Python/Libraries/Utils/build/test/bin'
```

I found that I needed a dummy **init**.py file, so I added that but it did not fix the issue.

Test Folder contents:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <username>  staff   461 Dec 14 12:39 TestSomething.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <username>  staff    53 Dec 13 22:40 __init__.py
```

Python Test Case:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
import os

class TestSomething(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    print("\nin TestSomething setUp()")
    print("CWD:", os.getcwd())

  def testMe(self):
    print("in TestSomething testMe()")

  def tearDown(self):
    print("in TestSomething tearDown()")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("TestSomething __main__")               # not executed via discover
  unittest.main()
  print("TestSomething has completed")          # not executed
```

The ANT target for the testing:

```
  <target name="-test-python"
          if="has.python.test.source"
          description="Run the Python tests.">
    <exec executable="python3"
          dir="${build.test.dir}/bin"
          osfamily="unix"
          failonerror="true">
      <arg value="-m" />
      <arg value="unittest" />
      <arg value="discover" />
      <arg value="-v" />
      <arg value="-s ${build.test.dir}/bin" />
      <arg value="-p Test*.py" />
      <arg value="-t ${dist.bin.dir}" />
    </exec>
    <echo level="info" message="* Python test/s complete. *" />
  </target>
```

Run from Terminal:

```
Craig-iMac:bin <username>$ python3 -m unittest discover -v -s /Users/<username>/Documents/Work/Python/Libraries/Utils/build/test/bin -p Test*.py
testMe (TestSomething.TestSomething) ...
in TestSomething setUp()
CWD: /Users/<username>/Documents/Work/Python/Libraries/Utils/build/test/bin
in TestSomething testMe()
in TestSomething tearDown()
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Is this an ANT issue (maybe 'exec' not the correct command) or am I missing something to do with Python's unittest ?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found an issue with ANT where the directory passed in with the

```
'<arg value="-s ${build.test.dir}/bin" />'
```

has a leading space (which is not present in other usage within ANT).

This causes os.path.abspath() (in discovery() in loader.py) to return a weird result, with the directory name duplicated like this:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Work/Python/Libraries/Utils/build/test/bin/ /Users/me/Documents/Work/Python/Libraries/Utils/build/test/bin
```

This fails the isdir() test resulting in the issue described in the original post.